# Is there a alternative default port number for https (443) which is above 1024?

Tags: http, https

We want to hide the port number in firefox address bar, we can't change to port 443 since we don't have root user. Is that possible?

For firefox browser, is there an 'alternative default https port' that is above 1024 and firefox will attempt when the url starts with https?

Comment: There is no alternative, I'm afraid. The port must be explicitly mentioned from the client side when the service is not listening from a default port.

Comment: @E_net4 Is it possible that we modify the unix routing table to forward port 443 to our port say 9000?

Comment: I don't know, but my opinion stands: you are thinking too much over a simple concept. Either try to get the required root permissions or just let it have an explicit port number.

Comment: @codeplay, I am removing my answer to this question since it didn't answer the true question here. Since it seemed to get popuar attention, I am posting it on a new question: http://stackoverflow.com/a/32478278/1670956

Comment: Now, please take a look at @AbuZubair 's answer, that sould be marked as right answer

Answer (score 3):

As the comments mention, no you can't. However, you can use any port you want, as long clients explicitly mention it. Anything 1024 or higher is a non-standard port and can be used.

Comment: What? No! Ports 0 to 1023 are *privileged* ports, 1024 to 49151 are *well-known* or *registered* ports. They should both appear in your `/etc/services` file. Everything higher than 41959 are dynamic ports that should not be held by any services.

Comment: @DaSourcerer: "Well-known" ports are merely registered default ports for a given service.  If you're not running the service that would answer on a given port, then you're free to use the port for whatever you like.  And it's only *suggested* that ephemeral ports be in the upper 1/4 of the port space.  TCP doesn't require it at all (let alone require that *only* ephemeral ports use that range), and the universe won't implode even once if you use them.