# Make Opera not assume I am using port 80

Tags: windows, port, opera

I have set up my local web server to use port 8000 for http and 8444 for https, because I often have contention for default port 80.

My web server starts fine, showing it uses port 8000 for http, and using Opera browser (my browser of choice), I can't open any site using, for example, http://abc.loc. I have to type in http://abc.loc:8000. So - I am assuming this is the browser's interpretation, or maybe something in Windows I can change, and not the web server. I want to be able to just type http://abc.loc, and the site opens.

Any ideas of how to tell Windows/Opera to use the port as assigned by the web server and not default port 80?

Comment: If you have contention for port 80 just kill the process that's using port 80

Comment: Thank you, but the problem is that when I work at another client, their system hogs port 80, and I need both applications at the same time. I therefore settled with my local web server on port 8000, which works, but is just inconvenience more than anything else.

Comment: So the client wants to run two websites at `http://abc.loc`? How would the browser even know which website to load?

Comment: No, my webserver is a PHP development environment, and the client's app is some legacy desktop app, which I am not even sure in what language it was written (it has a Windows XP-like interface). It has no configurable port options, and when that runs, I can't start my local web server.

Comment: Sounds like you need a proper enviroment to run your app, or make subdomain for you app with some reverse proxying. Setting a browser up for this seems overcamplicated. How about just making a bookmark of the abc.loc:8000 url?

Comment: There is one other option. But it will either cost you money or you have to click through the browser's "This page is not secure" page. Run your app on port 443 and install an SSL/TLS certificate. Then in your browser use `https://`

Comment: if you can use @slebetman 's idea (https port available), you can get a cert for free at https://letsencrypt.org/

Comment: @tonsteri The cert is free but you will need a domain name and a public http server to use it. I suppose you can use a free dynamic dns service and a free AWS or Azure account to do it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can do that.

80 is the TCP port assigned for HTTP traffic. That's the port that all public facing web servers listen to for HTTP. Logically browsers use this port by default.

Using anything else than this default is used for testing, "hiding" the service from crawlers and users, or because someone wants to start a web server without root privileges.

Comment: There are some "alternative ports" mentioned on the web for HTTP traffic, as mentioned here as well as other places: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32478277/is-there-any-standard-alternative-https-port. So -  not sure if non-accepted answer there is correct, but if it is correct, that it is officially alternative ports, then my requirement should not be that far out of reach.

Comment: There are some defaults that different apps use for dev env, 8080, 8000, etc. but they are not standardized in any way and routers / firewalls do not respect that. they are just conventions for developers.

Comment: Okay, seems I was wrong - they appear on https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_TCP_and_UDP_port_numbers#Registered_ports as official ports. But it still would make no sense to set a browser to use those as default

Comment: I also saw that Wikipedia article. But if they are official, my request should then be possible. I will keep your answer as the accepted answer, unless someone comes up with an answer that is provable to the contrary. Thanks for your assistance!

Comment: Hope you find a solution!